# How to generate function definition on fly dynamically based on the number of arguments?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am trying to build a helper function that would take a certain number of strings and return a another string which is the parameters part of the function definition.

I want to build a function definition on the fly. I am not familiar with the number of parameters. The function must be capable of returning a string with proper values
For example, I want this generate_function_def_on_fly(args:dict) to dynamically ouput ( {},{},{},{}).format(arg1, arg2, arg3). The dict will also
have the data type of the arg, so if the datatype is of string it has to output the varibales with quote

Example:

```
arg_dict={  
        "num_value":"number"
        "string_value": "string"
    }

    num_value = 5
    string_value = "hello"

    generate_function_def_on_fly(arg_dict) should output : (num_value, string_value) which will evaluate to (5, 'hello').
```

**My Use case** :  I am calling a stored procedure from my code, and I have to dynamically pass arguments to it, I am getting this arguments(arg_dict) from a config file. I have to generate the calling part with proper qualifiers. i.e quotes for strings and no quotes for numbers.

***Making it a bit more clear: I want to achieve this:***

```
def generate_args_on_fly(args:dict):
    # return ({id},' {name} '  )

args_dict = {
    "id" : "number",
    "name" : "string"
}

generate_args_on_fly(args_dict) # return ({id},' {name} '  )
```

I would like to use this with f"call {schema}.{stored_procedure}" + return value from generate_args_on_fly(args_dict)

Comment: uh... whats the use case of this?

Comment: So I am trying to call a stored procedure from my code and I have to generate the arguments part on the fly based on the args_dict passed as a dictionary

Comment: how is `id` and `name` defined? like not their type definitions, but their actual values?

Comment: Yes, they are stored as values

Comment: so like `id = 2` for example?

Comment: Okay, I think I dont need the dict, I just want the function to return f'({arg1!r}, {arg2!r})'. I think this could work. whats the use of "!r" in this statement ?

Comment: the `!r` is shorthand for `repr(...)`. it should be mentioned in docs on f-strings actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but I guess you could try with *f-strings* to see if it solves the issue:

```py
>>> num_value = 5
>>> string_value = "hello"
>>> f'({num_value!r}, {string_value!r})'
"(5, 'hello')"
```

For the dynamic equivalent of `str.format` or f-strings, you could create a wrapper function like how you had intended, and just call `repr()` on each argument:

```py
def generate_function_def_on_fly(*args):
    return f'({", ".join(repr(a) for a in args)})'

num_value = 5
string_value = "hello"

print(generate_function_def_on_fly(num_value, string_value))  # (5, 'hello')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am trying to achieve this:  

def generate_args_on_fly(args:dict):
    return f'({", ".join(repr(a) for a in sp_arguments)})'

args_dict = {
    "id" : "number",
    "name" : "string"
}

generate_args_on_fly(args_dict) # return ({id},' {name} '  )

Comment: so quick question, am i correct in thinking the `id` variable isn't already of `int` type?

Comment: @AJB I think the dynamic version of the function should work in that case. It supports a variadic number of arguments, so for example 2 or 5 args should work without any issue.

Comment: can you try like `generate_function_def_on_fly(id, name)`?

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for, thank You

Comment: awesome, glad to know that the solution was helpful!